# Changing scope variable in html5 tag event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am listing my videos with `ng-repeat` and I need to change an variable from `$scope` when a `html5` tag event fired.

```
<div ng-controller="VideoCtrl" ng-repeat="video in videos">
<video src="xx.mp4" onwaiting="video.state = 'waiting'" onplaying="video.state = 'playing'">
</video>
</div>
```

It gives me error of `video is not defined`.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry - but what exactly is the problem here? Could you clarify a bit more what you would like to have happen or what isn't happening?

Comment: I don't think that's the proper syntax for an HTML5 Video.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but you're not using the proper markup. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp